# Issues implementing Broadcasting with pusher

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, pusher

I am using laravel 5.2, and implementing real time notification when a task is completed. I have one event and one listeners. My end goal is to show a javascript alert on the page when the event gets pushed.

**App\Events\User\App\Trigger\MarkTopicComplete.php**

```
class MarkTopicComplete extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast{
...
public function broadcastWith(){
    return [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'topic_id' => $this->topic_id
    ];
}

public function broadcastOn(){
    return ['topic-complete'];
}
```

**App\Listeners\User\App\Trigger\MarkTopicComplete\LogActivity**

```
public function handle(MarkTopicComplete $event){
        $this->user_id = $event->user_id;
        $this->user_email = $event->user_email;
        $this->topic_id = $event->topic_id;
        Log::info('User '.$this->user_email.' has completed the TOPIC ID: '. $this->topic_id);
    }
```

**Front End**

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pusher = new Pusher('{{ config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key') }}', {
  encrypted: true
});
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var channel = pusher.subscribe('topic-complete');

channel.bind('App\\Events\\User\\App\\TriggerMarkTopicComplete', function(data) {
  // Over here i would like to alert the frontend with the topic id that is sent from the event.
  alert(data.topic_id);
});
</script>
```

**This is what i am recieving in my CONSOLE:**

```
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 204817.3725229
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"topic-complete"}}
1?session=OTk2NDUyOTMx&bundle=MQ%3D%3D&key=ODY4MTU1MjE4NWU0ZjFkYzY0YTI%3D&lib=anM%3D&version=My4yLj…:1 Uncaught TypeError: Pusher.ScriptReceivers[1] is not a function(anonymous function) @ 1?session=OTk2NDUyOTMx&bundle=MQ%3D%3D&key=ODY4MTU1MjE4NWU0ZjFkYzY0YTI%3D&lib=anM%3D&version=My4yLj…:1
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"topic-complete"}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on topic-complete for pusher:subscription_succeeded
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"App\\Events\\User\\EstudyAcademy\\Trigger\\MarkTopicComplete","data":{"user_id":1,"topic_id":2},"channel":"topic-complete"}
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on topic-complete for App\Events\User\EstudyAcademy\Trigger\MarkTopicComplete
```

As you can see i do recieve **"data":{"user_id":1,"topic_id":2}** but some how i cant do something like 
alert(data.user_id);
I think this might be because of this error 
**Uncaught TypeError: Pusher.ScriptReceivers[1] is not a function**

Comment: what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error with OctoberCMS(Laravel based CMS) and Pusher. Cause for my issue was I accidentally inserted pusher's js file (pusher.js) twice in the same page. Removing one from them solved the issue.